# Particular Function to Produce Vector Values

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have a function handle in matlab that I want to input a vector to return a vector that went through the function mapping. But this function varies in two parameters so I want to be able to input a value for that scalar as well as the function values.

The function is:

```
syms a
g = @(y) (exp(((-1/a).*atanh(y)).^2).*cos((2/a).*atanh(y)).*(1/a).*(1/(1+y.^2)));
```

or I can also do

```
g = @(y,a) (exp(((-1/a).*atanh(y)).^2).*cos((2/a).*atanh(y)).*(1/a).*(1/(1+y.^2)));
```

What I want to be able to do is

```
values = g([-0.5 0 0.5],3);
```

and return a three element vector.

but this returns an error and I'm not sure how I can get it to perform as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot one `.` with the last division:

```
g = @(y,a) (exp(((-1/a).*atanh(y)).^2).*cos((2/a).*atanh(y)).*(1/a).*(1./(1+y.^2)));
```

this works for me.

BTW: If you do it like this:

```
g = @(y,a) (exp(((-1./a)*atanh(y)).^2).*(cos((2./a)*atanh(y))).*((1./a)*(1./(1+y.^2))));
```

You can input both `y` and `a` as vectors:

```
g([-0.5 0 0.5],[1 2 3]')
ans =
   0.49202   1.00000   0.49202
   0.36789   0.50000   0.36789
   0.25747   0.33333   0.25747
```

this reads:

```
g([a b c], [d e f]')
ans = 
   g(a,d)    g(b,d)    g(c,d)
   g(a,e)    g(b,e)    g(c,e)
   g(a,f)    g(b,f)    g(c,f)
```

Comment: +1 for the first part. The second (both `y` and `a` vectors, along different dimensions) doesn't work for me. I don't think it's valid in Matlab. Are you using Octave, maybe?

Comment: I am using Octave and got and error along the solution and thought the error was Octaves fault ;-) Try the edited version.

Comment: The second version with both `y` and `a` as vectors would be dependent on the shape of the vector - whether one is row and the other is column. You will need to add `squeeze` and then `transpose`. See all reshaping commands: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/array-manipulation.html

Comment: In the resultant matrix, what rows and columns correspond to the values you passed in to g?

Comment: Just try it out with `g([-0.5 0 0.5],1)` and `g(0,[1 2 3]')` or read the edit.